# Sorting file names in a directory giving wrongly ordered results

Tags: c#, linq, directory

I have files in a directory with file names like this:

> Batch 1.10.18.xlsx 
>    Batch 2.10.18.xlsx 
>    ...
>   Batch 31.10.18.xlsx

As you see, they have this pattern: Batch `dd.mm.yy.xlsx`

I need to process them in the order by those dates in the file names.

**Code so far:**

```
private void processFiles(string BatchFilePath)
{
     IOrderedEnumerable<string> fileEntries = 
                Directory.GetFiles(BatchFilePath, "Batch *.xlsx")
                .OrderBy(f => GetFileDay(f));

     foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing File " + Path.GetFileName(fileName));

        // Code that read and process files 
     }

}

private int GetFileDay(string file)
{
    string s1=  file.Substring(7, 2);
    if (s1.Substring(1) == ".")
        s1 = s1.Substring(0, 1);
     return int.Parse(s1);
}
```

The code did not work. It still gives me files with names in the wrong order as shown below:

> Batch 25.10.18.xlsx 
>   Batch 22.10.18.xlsx...
>  
>   Batch 9.10.18.xlsx 
>   Batch 3.10.18.xlsx 
>   ...

Comment: show us the order expected v order seen

Comment: @John I imagine the "seen" order is "Batch 3.10.18" followed by "Batch 31.10.18" followed by "Batch 4.10.18".

Comment: can we assume you have no control over the naming of the files themselves?

Comment: the best answer may also depend on the quantity files, it this going to block a UI?

Comment: however one approach is to create a class model with a `DateTime` property.  you could build the datetime value from the file name, set a filename property, then sort on the list of model by the datetime property.

Comment: who knew sorting was so much fun! - some seriously complex solutions.  i think my suggestion is dead simple and easy to understand  - but that's just a reflection of myself :-)

Comment: I got kicked for writing 1 line of linq and you want to create whole model ... :-)

Answer (score 4):

Parse the string (such as "1.10.18") to a real `DateTime`(2018-10-01):

```
DateTime GetFileDay(string fileNameOrPath)
{
    string fileNameWithoutExt = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameOrPath);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(fileNameWithoutExt.Replace("Batch ", ""), "d.M.yy", null);
}
```

Comment: I think good answers shouldn't contains code-only solutions. Would you mind add some info about what and why your code is doing?

Comment: @vasily.sib Edited.

Comment: @skyoxZ thanks, could you also add full code from question, so everyone can see how do you use your `GetFileDay` method?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to parse the date from filename and sort based on datetime. Here is the modified code.

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string batchFilePath)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(batchFilePath))
            {
                var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(batchFilePath);
                var fileEntries = directoryInfo.GetFiles(@"Batch *.xlsx").Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(f => GetFileDay(f));
                return fileEntries;
            }

            return null;
        }

    private static DateTime GetFileDay(string file)
    {
        var date = default(DateTime);
        var extractedDate = Regex.Match(file, @"(\W\S*(\d[\d]{0,2}))").Value;
        extractedDate = extractedDate.Replace(".", "-").Trim();           
        DateTime.TryParseExact(extractedDate, "d-MM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out date);
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your file collection will be `IEnumerable<T>`, this will work sorting by real date [not string!] of your culture

```
var l  = new List<string>()
{
   "c:\\dev\\Batch 1.10.18.xlsx", 
   "c:\\dev\\Batch 2.10.18.xlsx", 
   "c:\\dev\\Batch 31.10.18.xlsx"
};

var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"); // pick culture is same as pick format. You need to pre-define one
var r = l.Select(x=>new{name = x, parts = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Split(" .".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)}).
        Select(a=> new {name = a.name, date = DateTime.Parse(a.parts[1] + "/" + a.parts[2] + "/" + a.parts[3], ci)}).
        OrderBy(x => x.date); //OrderByDescending(x => x.date);

r.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.name));
```

Output

> Batch 1.10.18.xlsx
>   Batch 2.10.18.xlsx
>   Batch 31.10.18.xlsx

This could be done more efficiently but less linear.

Comment: Isn't this is some over-engineered solution?

Comment: @vasily.sib its sorting by date, not string representation of date. I could do with 1 select but it would be longer to write for sake of example

Comment: Another answer is sorting by `DateTime` too, but it doesn't instantiate 2 anonimous objects for each filename and doesn't depend on exact culture:\

Comment: @vasily.sib another answer also uses 2 string searching\parsing methods and processes single file. While my example shows capability of LINQ.  Format is provided there, ok.? If every answer will be the same, life will be boring. My answer is about linq, date culture etc, and it DOES NOT SORT

Comment: `var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(BatchFilePath, "Batch *.xlsx").OrderBy(GetFileDay);` - is LINQ too. It just using private method instead of lambda.

Comment: @vasily.sib So, I added file parsing function simply because I wanted to see performance, etc. So, now. Time-wise same time my method vs another answer. And picking culture is no different than defining string `x.y.z`. They save file in specific date format, which corresponds to their culture. This is it. In fact, running in their systems that specifies that culture may not need to specify format at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what performance are you talking about. Let me disappoint you: LINQ is slower ther regular foreach loop. And I'm not argue about exact way you use `DateTime.ParseExact()`, I'm talking that your answer is not logicaly differ from another, already posted one, which use `DateTime.ParseExact()` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Regex. Then you can do OrderBy/OrderByDescending on Linq:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{2}");
var orderByDateList = items.Where(po => r.IsMatch(po)).OrderByDescending(po => DateTime.ParseExact(r.Match(po).Value, "d.M.yy", null)).ToList(); // lines that match date pattern
```

Comment: I take it you didn't test this :) `d.M.yy` - `m` is minutes, not months.

Comment: Come on guys. There is already an answer that is based on `DateTime.ParseExact()`, why are you adding another one? Why this is not just a comment ("Hey, you may also use a `Regex` for this")? Should I add another answer, that is invoking a HTTP request to remote neural network, that can extract a date from string?

Comment: @vasily.sib Ok, Vasya, you just trying to control everybody's ideas, approaches, etc. Let OP to pick what they like. Let voter vote. Variety of answers is good for OP because for someone the whole new world may just opened

Comment: @T.S. I'm not trying to control anyone, for sure. What I want is that SO will concentrate on improving existing answers, instead of copy-pasting existing ones.

Comment: Gauravsa, sorry if my example about neural network is looking rough, it is just first another example that came to my mind.

Comment: @vasily.sib Let me disappoint you. SO will never be "clean". Company with 10 devs can't get their code clean and reused. Copy/paste all the time. And you want SO with thousands of users be clean. You can dream but it ain't gonna happen. Why didn't you vote the question up. Its kind of cool one

Comment: @T.S. I'm not talking about clean code. I'm talking about "clean" threads (question and coresponding answers).

Comment: This working. I test with OrderBy and OrderByDescending. Works

Comment: @vasily.sib: apology accepted even though i cudnt understand what it was for lol :). Edited the regex it takes 1,2 digits for month.